# How to start mariadb service on nginx server?

Tags: mysql, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I have been trying to set up a server and I am facing problems while starting mariadb. It giving errors in console. I followed some tutorials and search on internet to find solution But I did not get a solution to start mariadb.

```html
mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2014-06-02 22:48:58 BST; 33min ago
  Process: 10042 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-wait-ready $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 10041 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10013 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 10041 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service

Jun 02 22:48:56 ultrasonicfortress mysqld_safe[10041]: 140602 22:48:56 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'.
Jun 02 22:48:56 ultrasonicfortress mysqld_safe[10041]: 140602 22:48:56 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Jun 02 22:48:58 ultrasonicfortress mysqld_safe[10041]: 140602 22:48:58 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
Jun 02 22:48:58 ultrasonicfortress systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 02 22:48:58 ultrasonicfortress systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jun 02 22:48:58 ultrasonicfortress systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
```

Comment: Have you tried this code? `systemctl start mariadb`

Comment: yes, i have tried this , but not running